# Bind multiple certificates on a port in Windows server

Tags: x509certificate, windows-server, netsh

I want to bind 2 certificates on a port in my Windows server.

But it doesn't let me add the second certificate once one has already been added for it. Or unless I clear the bindings for the port using `netsh delete` command.

Adding the second certificate shows this error -

**System error 183. Cannot create file when that file already exists**

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:2195 certhash="$thumbprint" appid='{472f53d0-29e1-4cf4-ba9c-79f362d8f6fa}'
```

Is it possible to bind multiple certificate to the same port?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i dont see anything wrong in the question..u shud give a reason when you downvote a question

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution for this. Surprisingly I didn't find a single resource about this across the web.

It seems that you can't bind multiple certificates if you set the IP as `0.0.0.0` (which I think, is wildcard)

So, for the other certificate, I had to use some other IP.

Since in my case the destination IP address is known and is fixed, which is `17.x.x.x` IP address block (Apple) .

So for the second certificate, I changed the `ipport` in the command to `17.0.0.0:2195`.

And voila, it worked!

Comment: Sorry, I take that back. Using an actual IP-number didnt work for me; using `192.168.1.10` as an IP, and doing the ssl assignment twice, with different certs (and thus different certhash), fails if its already bound. Maybe I misunderstood you, but are using two different IPnbr when binding?

Comment: yes one with 0.0.0.0 and the other with 17.something..and it works fine for me

Comment: Aha, i see. So, three certificates wouldn't work then? =)

Comment: Hi, just wondering must it only be 17.0.0.0... Can it be any other number?

Comment: no @user1034912 it can be any IP in my opinion